# advancedNewFile plugin in sublime

Tags: plugins, sublimetext3

In sublime text editor there is a plugin AdvancedNewFile, which allows with a shortcut open a downside bar and create a new file easy and fast.

When I have a lot of folders in my project and I want to create new file in one of them I have to type the location to the folder, which is frustrating.

Well, my question is, can I make this downside bar appear with right path, when I right click on the folder in project structure and select "Create a new file"?

P.S. To be more clear, I want a behavior similar to Atom new file creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already possible with the [**`SideBarEnhancements`**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SideBarEnhancements) plugin. Just select a folder in your project, right-click on it, select **`New File...`**, type in the file name, and you're done.